# Python: how to simultaneously add two lists to a list?

Tags: python, list, append

Let's say I have a list

```
l1 = []
```

another list

```
l2 = ['a','b']
```

and two variables

```
u = 1
z = 2
```

Now I would like to add l2 to l1 and the two variables as a list to l1 as well. One can do it in two steps using append:

```
l1.append(l2)
l1.append(list((u,z)))
```

which gives me the desired output

```
[['a', 'b'], [1, 0]]
```

But something like

```
l1.append(l2, list((u,z)))
```

does not work. Is there a way to get the same output I obtain for the two steps in a nice oneliner i.e. can one simultaneously append a list by two lists?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
l1.extend([l2, [u,z]])
```

`append` can only add one element to a list.
`extend` takes a list and adds all the elements in it to other list.

Comment: That works fine, thanks! I tried it with "extend" but called it as "append " using l1.extend(l2, list((u,z))) which gave me the same error - the [] solve the issue.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `extend` as follows:

`l1.extend([l2,[u,z]])`

Or just:

`l1 + [l2] + [[u,z]]`

Comment: Thanks for providing an alternative solution!

Comment: No problem, @Cleb, next time you can upvote instead of giving thanks on a comment. It's more useful for other users to see if the answer is useful.

Answer (score 1):

You can use any of the following methods:

**Method 1 :**

`>>> l1.extend([l2, [u,z]])`
`>>> l1`
`[['a', 'b'], [1, 2]]`

`append`: Appends object at end
`extend`: Extends list by appending elements from the iterable

**Method 2 :**

`>>> l1 += [l2] + [[u, z]]`
`>>> l1`
`[['a', 'b'], [1, 2]]`

Comment: that's not the desired output in the OP's question

Comment: Changed the code now, now getting the desired output.

Comment: Yes, that's the accepted answer but thanks for your efforts anyway!

Answer (score 1):

This is simple by creating a generator

`import itertools`
`for item in itertools.chain(listone, listtwo):`
   `# do what you want to do with this merged list`

Comment: What would be the advantage of this method compared to the accepted answer?

Comment: Itertools will help not only just to merge but you can do permutations and combinations as per need...